# Как выбрать строки с определенным годом в datetime?

Tags: база-данных, php, mysql

Есть таблица и в ней колонка registered (тип данных datetime) формат даты данных при отправки а базу date("Y-m-d H:i:s"). Как выбрать только те строки где год к примеру колонки registred = 2012

Comment: @Cone, y Вас очень маленький процент принятых ответов. Если в предыдущих вопросах вы получали верные/полезные/нужные ответы, отметьте их как правильный. Это как минимум мотивирует потенциального ответчика.

Comment: google + mysql datetime functions 1. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html 2. http://phpclub.ru/mysql/doc/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: Всем спасибо, разобрался сам, в мое случае запрос выглядит следующим образом, $comp = $db->query("select * from user_ts where DATE_FORMAT(registered,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i %s') = 2013")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

Answer (score 2):

Лучше так:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE YEAR(registered) = 2012
```

Ваш вариант более медленный

Comment: Для индексированной колонки метки времени самый быстрый вариант, это [оператор BETWEEN][1] без операций над значениями колонки. 

 [1]: http://tigor.com.ua/blog/2008/08/23/date_comparison_by_between_operator_of_mysql/